# Can't find AWS Identity Pool's rules setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html#using-rules-to-assign-roles-to-users

As stated in the document:

> Rules are evaluated in order, and the IAM role for the first matching rule is used, unless CustomRoleArn is specified to override the order. For more information about user attributes in Amazon Cognito user pools, see Configuring User Pool Attributes.
>
> You can set multiple rules for an authentication provider in the identity pool (federated identities) console. Rules are applied in order. You can drag the rules to change their order. The first matching rule takes precedence. If the match type is NotEqual and the claim doesn't exist, the rule is not evaluated. If no rules match, the Role resolution setting is applied to either Use default Authenticated role or DENY.

My understanding is that we can customize these rules to map the JWT token's field to a specific AWS role granting.

Yet I couldn't find any options of creating/editing these rules on the AWS Console

[image: Identity Pool settings]

Am I misreading the documentation? Or is this an undelivered feature or something?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that custom roles using Cognito Identity Pool only works with Cognito User Pool

User Pool can only be integrated with external SAML IDP (not JWT), so I think it's not possible to do access control for JWT bearers with Identity Pool

I guess what we can do is create multiple Identity Pools for multiple IAM Roles and do the access control from the IDP, even then we'll have to create multiple IDP clients for multiple Identity Pools

Answer (score 0):

The moved it.

In the Identity Pool dashboard,

- Click 'User Access' tab
- Click on an identity provider

The rules for that identity provider are there.